# sortable & Nestable Category how can i send it to server?

Tags: ajax, jquery-nestable

Hello i use [Sortable & Nestable structure](https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/ui/sortable-nestable.html)
how can i save this data to database with php.
It's enough for me if you can provide a resource to guide me.

My Data :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "5"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "8"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "9"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "10"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "12"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "14"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "13"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "15"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "16"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My Database structure :
[image: Database Table]
Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to save this data to the database but I can't. I searched on the internet but couldn't find enough results. I will be very happy if you help me

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are basically asking us to either design, or design and write code from a Specification. 
That is  not what StackOverflow is for, we help each other fix code related issues we are having, we dont write code for you

Comment: Sorry . It's enough for me if you can provide a resource to guide me.

Comment: Do you have that data structure already passed from the front end to php for processing? Or is there a problem with passing the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the tree recursively keeping track of current parent, then pushing to db each of its children as child - parent.

```js
var tree = [{id:"1",children:[{id:"2",children:[{id:"3"},{id:"4"},{id:"5"},{id:"6"},{id:"7"},{id:"8"},{id:"9"},{id:"10"}]},{id:"11",children:[{id:"12"},{id:"14"},{id:"13"},{id:"15"},{id:"16"}]}]}];

var db = [];

function iterate(children, parent) {
  parent = parent || 0;
  children.forEach(function(child) {
    db.push ({child: child.id, parent: parent})
    if (child.children) {
      iterate(child.children, child.id)
    }
  })
}

iterate(tree)

console.log(db)
```